# Looking for a better way to handle all items from one url

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I have one spider to crawl a list of urls, like

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
        'http://www.example.com/2.html',
        'http://www.example.com/3.html',
    ]
 def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    records = response.xpath('//*[@id="feed-main-list"]/li')
    for rec in records:
        item = MyItem()
        item['spiderUrl'] = response.request.url
        item['url']     = rec.xpath('.//*[@class="feed-block-title"]/a/@href').extract_first().strip()
        item['title']   = rec.xpath('string(.//*[@class="feed-block-title"])').extract_first().strip()
        item['lastUpdate'] = 'success'
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

For each url, i need to handle the items together(analyze data, send email if something happens) and as soon as possible. I choose the pipeline to do it. But in pipeline, it just receives item one by one from from.
So, i try to pack the items into one container item in spider. 
In spider,

```
container = ContainerItem()
container['url'] = response.request.url
container['itemist'] = items
return [container]
```

and in pipeline,

```
> def process_item(self, item, spider):
>     item['itemList']
>     n = len(item['itemList'])
>     for i in item['itemList']:
>         item = dict(i)
>         ...
```

So, my questions are:
1. Is it a good way to implement it according to my requirement?
2. Packing a list of items into one container item like that seems very ugly. Is there any Scrapy-style method to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most logical solution would be to combine all items into one. Nesting in a dictionary is a very common concept and it might appear complicated and dirty but really is optimal and easy as long as you don't go 10 levels deep.

To do that simply wrap your `items` list in a dictionary, like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    records = response.xpath('//*[@id="feed-main-list"]/li')
    for rec in records:
        item = MyItem()
        item['spiderUrl'] = response.request.url
        item['url']     = rec.xpath('.//*[@class="feed-block-title"]/a/@href').extract_first().strip()
        item['title']   = rec.xpath('string(.//*[@class="feed-block-title"])').extract_first().strip()
        item['lastUpdate'] = 'success'
        items.append(item)
    return {'items': items}
```

Now your pipeline will receive all of the items as one item, that you can unpack, sort and do whatever you wish.
In scrapy this approach is very common and even used with [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) if those are used instead of pure `scrapy.Item`, which to clarify is just slightly modified python dictionary!